Issue with Calculating Terms of OEIS Sequence A187278 Using SageMath
I’m trying to compute the terms of the OEIS sequence $A187278$ using SageMath. This sequence, described as "The radical part of the expression whose continued fraction has periodic part $1, 2, \dots, n$" begins as follows: $5, 3, 37, 156, 65029$ etc. in the OEIS database OEIS A187278
I'm trying to calculate its terms by using sagemath, in particular using the continued fractions package as in continued fractions sagemath. According to the definition of the sequence, if I'm not wrong, the terms of this sequence should be precisely the ones given by the command .value().parent().inject_variables() over a element of the class continued fraction.

$ a(1) = 5 $ because the continued fraction (cf) of $ \frac{-1 +
   \sqrt{5}}{2} $ is $[0; (1)*]$

list = [0],[1]
cf = continued_fraction(list)
print(cf)
print(cf.value())
cf.value().parent().inject_variables()

returning
[0; (1)*]
1/2*sqrt5 - 1/2
Defining sqrt5


$ a(2) = 3 $ because the cf of $ -1 + \sqrt{3} $ is $[0; (1,2)*]$.

list = [0],[1,2]
cf = continued_fraction(list)
print(cf)
print(cf.value())
cf.value().parent().inject_variables()

returning
[0; (1, 2)*]
sqrt3 - 1
Defining sqrt3


$a(3) = 37 $ because the cf of  $\frac{-4 + \sqrt{37}}{3}$ is $[0; (1,2,3)*]$.

list = [0],[1,2,3]
cf = continued_fraction(list)
print(cf)
print(cf.value())
cf.value().parent().inject_variables()

returning
[0; (1, 2, 3)*]
1/3*sqrt37 - 4/3
Defining sqrt37

Here is where the problem begins: The problem is that this code returns 39 instead of the expected value of 156 for $ a(4) $.

$ a(4) $ should be 156 according to OEIS, but I encounter an issue
when trying to calculate it.

list = [0],[1,2,3,4]
cf = continued_fraction(list)
print(cf)
print(cf.value())
cf.value().parent().inject_variables()

returning
[0; (1, 2, 3, 4)*]
2/5*sqrt39 - 9/5
Defining sqrt39

This is not the only discrepancy, by computing the expected values for the circle $[0;(1,2,3,...,n)*]$ the sequence is the following:
def A187278_list(n):
    A187278 = []
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        lista = [i for i in range(1, j + 1)]
        seq = [0], lista
        cf = continued_fraction(seq)
        A187278.append(cf.value().parent().inject_variables())

returning for A187278_list(20)
Defining sqrt5
Defining sqrt3
Defining sqrt37
Defining sqrt39
Defining sqrt65029
Defining sqrt4171
Defining sqrt29964677
Defining sqrt13493990
Defining sqrt635918528029
Defining sqrt71216963807
Defining sqrt1951254635768065
Defining sqrt7846010029748338
Defining sqrt191780091068145774653
Defining sqrt35152731838745826
Defining sqrt2129087866550404672890001
Defining sqrt237225487734743843423231
Defining sqrt633378381185791927931233429813
Defining sqrt2821105820748751669061528819
Defining sqrt18596448333191936960600383494952901
Defining sqrt18628552625863073843486523343751922

Remark, the term $a(5)=65029$ coincide with the one expected from my sagemath code.
Questions:

Is there an error in my usage of continued fractions  in
SageMath, or could there be an alternative explanation for why the
value differs from what’s listed in OEIS?

Could this discrepancy be due to an issue with the definition or
implementation of the sequence in OEIS?   How can I correctly compute
the term $a(4) = 156$ in SageMath?

Any insights or suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly
appreciated!



I just found my own mistake. It is just simply because the prime decomposition of 156 = $2^2\cdot 3\cdot 13$ contains a squared factor so that it reduces to sqrt(39)

Here is a way to put the hands in sage on the oeis.org/A187278 sequence, which is slightly unclear in its definition, because the "radical part" is not well defined (in that context):
def a(n):
    val = continued_fraction([[0], [1..n]]).value()
    F = val.parent()
    return ZZ( (val.numerator().list()[1] * F.gens()[0])^2 )


Then the first twenty values, computed by the above code are consistent with the oeis reference:
for n in [1..20]:
    print(n, a(n))

1 5
2 3
3 37
4 156
5 65029
6 66736
7 29964677
8 121445910
9 635918528029
10 640952674263
11 1951254635768065
12 7846010029748338
13 191780091068145774653
14 192496359548972143176
15 2129087866550404672890001
16 2135029389612694590809079
17 633378381185791927931233429813
18 70527645518718791726538220475
19 18596448333191936960600383494952901
20 74514210503452295373946093375007688

